# MS Access - INTO clause containing square brackets in file path

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this simple SQL query that creates a new table in another MS Access database file, getting the data from a table in the current MS Access file where the query is running.

```
SELECT * INTO [<FILE PATH>].NEWTABLE FROM TABLE
```

However, the file path contains square brackets, creating conflicts while reading the file path (it ends after the first closed square bracket that is occurring in the file path).

How can avoid this conflict in the file path?

Comment: simply don't use that characters in a filepath

Comment: And if I can't? I can't believe there isn't any other workaround...

Comment: no, there isn't a workaround for that, you need to avoid it,.

Comment: Try backticks for enclosure symbols which is synonymous to square brackets in Access SQL.

Comment: Am able to set a link to table via External Data wizard. Why do you have process to create table instead of adding records to existing?

Comment: Backticks don't work. I have never seen them used in Access query.

Answer (score 1):

I think, square brackets and other special symbols in file path or name is problem.
If not impossible change that path, try reverse task.

```
Function Test2()
Dim filePath As String
Dim sqlExpr As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim currDbPath As String
    currDbPath = CurrentDb.Name
    filePath = "<file path with [ and].accdb>"
    Set db = OpenDatabase(filePath)
    sqlExpr = "SELECT * INTO NEWTABLE4  FROM [" & currDbPath & "].tbTest1"
    db.Execute (sqlExpr)
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

In case where both files contain square brackets, use TransferDatabase method)

```
Function test5()
Dim sourceTableName As String
Dim destTableName As String
Dim destDbPath As String
Dim sqlExpr As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
    destDbPath = "<file path with [ and].accdb>"
    sourceTableName = "tbTest1"
    destTableName = "NewTable7"
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", _
        destDbPath, acTable _
       , sourceTableName, sourceTableName
       ' case 1 - when table names different  - created link
       ', sourceTableName, destTableName 
    Set db = OpenDatabase(destDbPath)

    sqlExpr = "SELECT * INTO NEWTABLE  FROM " & sourceTablename 
    ' or in case 1  - linked table
    'sqlExpr = "SELECT * INTO NEWTABLE  FROM " & destTablename 

    db.Execute (sqlExpr)
    ' delete table destTableName, if necessary
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Edit example. In 2nd case,if parameters `sourceTableName, destTableName`  is the same, TransferDatabase creates copy of table in destination base. From this table, or from linked table in 1 case, you can copy to target table.
As you originally intended

```
SELECT * INTO NEWTABLE FROM destTableName
```

Then delete or not  this (temporary) table or link.

From MS Access doc:`If you import a table from another Access database that's a linked table in that database, it will still be linked after you import it. That is, the link is imported, not the table itself.`
This feature should be taken into account when using the function TransferDatabase.
@Trial4life says "If I use DoCmd.TransferDatabase, then it creates a linked table in the backup file, while I need a normal table".  Most likely, he does not have the source table itself in the database, but a link to it.
In this case  `SELECT * INTO NEWTABLE FROM destTableName` is necessarily.

Comment: The error still occurs, since currDbPath still contains square brackets that alters the sql query...

Comment: Are the brackets in both file paths?

Comment: Yes, both file paths contain brackets

Comment: I'll add simple solution for this case in my answer

Comment: Does this work even if I'm trying to copy a table linked to a SharePoint List into a local table in the backup .ACCDB file? Is the DoCmd.TransferDatabase the same?

Comment: This works also when source table in your database file is ``linked table`` from another file.  Special case with SharePoint not available to test for me. I presume,yes, this works.

Comment: See also ``DoCmd.TransferSharePointList`` method.

Comment: If I use `DoCmd.TransferDatabase`, then it creates a linked table in the backup file, while I need a normal table...
Instead the `DoCmd.TransferSharePointList` doesn't seem to have the option `destDbPath` to tell in which file I want to export the table...

Comment: Should declare all variables: `db` and `sqlExpr` are not declared. Extraneous **&** characters at end of SQL statements. With TransferDatabase, can specify destination table name and don't need to open db object and the SQL is not needed and no 'temp' table or link. Otherwise, code works.

Comment: @June7 thanks for the comment. I'll fix the code. I collected it from two functions and didn't have enough time to smooth it out.

Comment: But you kept the SQL part. In my test it was not needed. TransferDatabase can name the destination table whatever you want.

Comment: Although the name of the table "NEWTABLE" says that need to completely copy the table, I'm not shure, is initial task to copy full table or insert all rows to existing table. When ``copy full table`` overwriting existed,I agree, no need to kept SQL part.